# How to use IN query?

Tags: mysql, sql

In mp_cities table city_name and city_id are the fields

```
city_id        city
--------------------
  1            Chennai
  2            Bangalore
  3            Kerala
```

In profile table

```
user_email         city_type 
------------------------------
abc@gmail.com      1,2,3
```

I am using the following query

```
SELECT city_name 
  FROM mp_cities 
 WHERE city_id IN (SELECT city_type 
                     FROM profile 
                     WHERE  user_email='abc@gmail.com')
```

this query will result Chennai. 
I have to get all the cities

Comment: Profile table looks confusing. City_type field in your example is a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` in MySQL.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM        mp_cities a
                INNER JOIN  profile  b
                    ON FIND_IN_SET(a.city_id, b.city_type)
WHERE   b.user_email = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

but the best way so far I can think is to normalize the table properly.

mp_cities

- city_id (PK)
- city
- other columns

profile

- user_id (PK)
- other columns

mp_cities _profile

- city_id (FK)
- user_id (FK)

Answer (score 3):

You would get the desired result if the `profile` table looked like this:

```
user_email     city_type
------------------------
abc@gmail.com  1
abc@gmail.com  2
abc@gmail.com  3
```

That is, the inner `SELECT` must return several rows, each with a number, NOT one row with a comma-delimited set of numbers.

Comment: +1 And we should advise Athi to use numeric *user_id*s as indexes instead of email.

Comment: because user_email primary key

Answer (score 1):

Try to join both tables with [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function like this:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM mp_cities c
  JOIN profile p
    ON FIND_IN_SET(c.city_id,p.city_type) > 0;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/982fd3/1)